# Submitting to the App Store Using Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store

So! Thought this would be easy trying to use TestFlighApp inside itunesconnect but this is what stops me:

[image: this bundle is invalid. the key uirequireddevicecapabilities contains value]

How I got this message is: **Product** > **Archive** > Success! > **Submit to App Store...** > **Select My Team** > **Submit** > **Uploading Archive ( Verifying assets with the iTunes store** BAM! Message

Things I've Tried

1. Verified my Project: since this Xcode project was created around 2011, I noticed I had to validate settings by clicking **Editor** > **Validate Settings...** didn't fix my problem. actually created more ;) but all fixed
2. Added the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist: I have only **arm64** afer removing **armv7**, **armv7s**

Let me know if anything else is needed to help help me, I'll edit :)

Comment: have you tried resetting the list of architectures to default?

Comment: And what do you mean by that? I've never been exposed to "updating" architectures :(

Comment: you need to add armv7 at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but by removing the array, UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, the issue was resolved. Not sure why that array was added to my Info.plist but problem solved :)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and answers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<spoiler>
    just wait...
</spoiler>
```

[image: http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/102]

It happend to me when I tried to avoid develop my app for iPhone4s because of clear understanding - this is the work for nothing. In next half a year of after one year this device goes out.

I tried to limited

```
armv7s for below

<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

[image: after limit]

and get

[image: non-submit]

change limits everywhere

[image: limits]

result is the same: need to add support for **armv7** =(

[image: nooo]

Ok. Get everything back...

[image: everything back.]

and:

[image: done]

The problem is armv7 is a minimum that required for 8.4 and 8.0 as well. So you can not avoiding it. Enjoy.